# DocuSign API - How to get callback response after user authentication?

Tags: delphi, authentication, docusignapi, indy, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to implement the [Implicit Grant REST API of DocuSign](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-implicit). I'm confused as to what needs to happen right after the user logs in. This is a stand-alone native Windows desktop application, not a web service or page.

I got as far as to open an embedded browser window, navigating to the correct URI for login, and the user is able to successfully login. I further have an HTTP server running in this application as well which is to receive the callback. In fact, the callback does work, I do get an incoming HTTP GET command. However, there is nothing usable in this callback response. No special headers, parameters, body, nothing.

Before I tried the Implicit Grant API, I first tried the JWT Grant method, before realizing it wasn't the right approach. But my point is, at least I had a `code` parameter in the callback command. But after shifting over to use the Implicit Grant method, this response is empty.

According to the documentation:

> After consent has been granted, the Authentication Service verifies that the client application is valid and has access to the requested scope. If so, it redirects the access token to the provided callback URI in a hash fragment.
>
> The response contains the following hash fragment parameters:
>
> .......

It even shows an example response:

```
http://localhost/#access_token=eyJ0eXAi.....9LyiFrUqvdw&expires_in=28800&token_type=bearer&state=a39fh23hnf23
```

But, as mentioned, the callback response I receive has nothing of notable value. It's essentially just empty.

What am I missing here? What's the correct approach to complete the authentication process and proceed to actually using the API?

NOTE: I'm using Delphi, so none of the examples provided by DocuSign are compatible.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered what I was doing wrong. It was some confusion and terminology mix-ups. When I stated that my callback URI does in fact work, that's in reference to it triggering my HTTP server listening from within the app - but had no usable data.

However, what I *actually* need to do is not capture the request in the HTTP server, but rather catch the URI that the embedded browser navigates to after user authentication. Once I sniffed into this browser's URI after successful login, now I can in fact see `access_token`.

So `callback uri` and `redirect uri` are the exact same thing, but can be easily misinterpreted. I kinda have two different definitions of them, where callback is to respond to original caller, and redirect means to navigate from one page to another automatically.

Now I'm curious whether I should even need an HTTP server, or if I could just blindly throw any arbitrary redirect URI (of course registered in the account) and just grab the URI after the embedded browser navigates.

As to why my HTTP server didn't see this data, but the embedded browser did, is beyond me. It should match in both sides.

Just for reference, the embedded browser I'm using is Chromium (DCEF3), and the HTTP server is Indy's `TIdHTTPServer` component.

---

**UPDATE**

As noted in the comments, the HTTP Server does not receive the "bookmark" portion of the URI by design, because the bookmark is a client-side only thing. There's no reason at all why it should ever be sent to the server. Hence the level of security - since that information will ONLY be used by the client, and not the server, it would be risky to send the `access_token` to the server, over the web. So it keeps it local to the client-side browser. That's why I saw this data on the browser, and not the HTTP server request handler.

Comment: I don't think you need a server. You just need to manage your browser. It receives back the access token in the response, in the fragment section of the url. The trick is this that you need to catch that url/uri, as you're doing. Good work!

Comment: @LarryK I'm willing to bet the HTTP server component I'm using (Indy for Delphi) somehow disregards the "Bookmark" portion of the URI, as the "Bookmark" is typically only used on the client-side - I can't imagine real-case situations why a bookmark would be needed by the server. So it's likely the bookmark is discarded by the server, thus why the HTTP request was empty with nothing usable. I do find it somewhat odd why the mechanism would put that in the bookmark and not the parameters.

Comment: @LarryK I added the `indy` tag, hoping that a fellow Indy developer Remy might chime in with some added info on that point. Because when this HTTP server receives a request, the request info has everything except for any bookmark info - and when observing the "raw" HTTP command, it shows the URI, including parameters, but no bookmark string.

Comment: Bookmarks are not part of URLs themselves, so no client should ever be requesting a bookmark. It is not that the server discards bookmarks, but that the server should not be receiving bookmarks in the first place.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for that clarification. So in the end, I don't even really need an HTTP server - as long as I have a legit URL I can set it to redirect to, I can grab that URL from the Chromium embedded browser and use that - which I've already implemented and is so far successful.

Comment: You don't even need a legit URL, just something unique that you can look for when the server tells the browser to redirect to it (and, of course, you would need to block the browser from actually requesting it, since it doesn't really exist).

Comment: @RemyLebeau True, good point. I could just point it at `http://localhost/` and catch that when the browser tries to navigate to it. Didn't even think of capturing it early like that. Thanks for the tip(s). Although I also wonder if DocuSign checks for validity of a callback URL, since it needs to be pre-registered in the account. However, I did test with a real valid LocalHost HTTP server, and it didn't seem to care, so long as the redirect URL matched in both the request and the config.

Comment: Come to think of it, for security reasons, this data was probably put in the bookmark for the sole purpose that it's not supposed to go to the server.

Comment: Remy is right that the bookmark (fragment), per the spec, is not sent to servers. Jerry, you're also right that the Implicit Grant puts the access token in the fragment since it is only needed by the client (browser), and the goal is to minimize its potential leakage.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer** 
Use Implict Grant when you do **not** have a backend server as part of the authentication flow. Implicit Grant is for anytime the client id's secret / RSA private key can't be protected--anytime there isn't a secure server in the application's architecture. This includes mobile apps (since the app can be reverse engineered, single page apps (React, Angular, etc) and desktop/thick client apps (eg Delphi apps).

I use Implicit Grant for my DocuSign applications I write in React.

In your case, you're writing a "thick client app" that runs entirely on the desktop.

Since DocuSign's OAuth2 Implicit Grant flow matches the standard, a good place to start is the framework's examples for authenticating with other OAuth2 identity providers.

**For Delphi**, see their example for [Accessing Facebook API](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/REST_Client_Library#Accessing_Facebook_API). While not exactly the same as DocuSign's Implicit Grant flow, it is close enough. In particular, note how Facebook also returns the access token in the URL fragment when `response_type=token` is requested (as is done in the Delphi example).

Quote from Facebook [authentication docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow):

> response_type = token. Response data is included as a URL fragment and contains an access token. **Desktop apps must use this setting** for response_type. This is most useful when the client will be handling the token.

[Emphasis added]

### Bottom line: use/modify the Delphi example of authenticating with Facebook since DocuSign is similar. If you can't get it to work, ask Delphi customer service for help, referencing the Facebook authentication example.

PS Once you've solved the problem, please provide your own answer that includes the code you use--to help others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I just now figured out what was going wrong. Although I provide a callback URI, which does in fact trigger my HTTP server, it does not include the `access_token` param, or any params. **BUT**, the embedded browser, just after user login, DOES in fact navigate to my redirect URI along with necessary param(s). It's really confusing that `callback uri` and `redirect uri` are the same thing.

Comment: Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit Grant is mainly for Mobile Apps, for Desktop Applications you need to use [Authorization Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant), with this approach you will get code back in the RedirectUrl. Also please note to select `Authorization Code Grant` radio option in your Integrator Key configuration.

[image]

Comment: The docs sure do emphasize that the Authorization Code Grant method is for server/client web applications, which is way not what I'm doing. Are you sure that's the correct solution for desktop applications?

Comment: I thought Desktop application means WebApp (browser based), so are you having a standalone application? Because for Authorization code grant it needs a browser based App on your side to read the code. If you cannot have browser based app to read the code from the URL, and if you need to get only one time consent then best is to go with JWT consent where it will ask end-user to give one-time consent and once consent is given then your Application can generate Access Token for that user.

Comment: Yes, standalone Windows application. It does have an embedded browser for login, and HTTP abilities - but when trying JWT, it was even more involved and difficult, specifically when it comes to actually generating the JWT. I took the course of an easier method, although not as secure, because this will be a small internal company application using it.

Comment: There are many libraries which can help you in creating JWT, please check out libraries in diff languages in jwt.io website.

Comment: Hi Amit, Implicit Grant is for anytime the client id's secret / RSA private key can't be protected--anytime there isn't a secure server in the application's architecture. This includes mobile apps (since the app can be reverse engineered, single page apps (React, Angular, etc) and thick client apps (eg Delphi apps).